# Несколько графиков с одинаковым делением осей

Tags: python, matplotlib

Хотелось бы, чтобы два разных графика имели общую ось Y, т.е. чтобы не было как на картинке ниже. Например, чтобы и 80, и 60, были каждая на своей линии соответственно.

Вроде как надо убрать смещение. Пытался сделать так, но не работает:

```
a.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import random
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
from queue import Empty, Queue
from time import time as timer
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from numpy import block


def get_xy_from_db(id):  # generate dummy data
    time.sleep(random.random())  # emulate blocking function
    list_x = list(range(1, 16))
    list_y = list(random.sample(range(0, 100), 15))
    res_lst = list_x + list_y
    return res_lst


def poll_db(id, emit):
    while True:
        # time.sleep(interval)
        emit(get_xy_from_db(id))


def poll_db_2(id, emit):  # NOTE: interval is independant from the delay
    while True:
        # time.sleep(interval)
        emit(get_xy_from_db(id))


def make_x_y(list_a):
    done_x = list_a[:15]
    done_y = list_a[15:]
    return done_x, done_y


def start_polling_loop(root, q, delay):
    def loop():

        root.after(1000, loop)
        a.clear()
        try:
            data = q.get(block=False)
            x, y = make_x_y(data)
            a.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
            a.plot(x, y)
            canvas.draw()
        except Empty:
            return

    root.after_idle(loop)  # start


def start_polling_loop_2(root, q_2, delay):
    def loop():
        root.after(1000, loop)
        a1.clear()
        try:
            data = q_2.get(block=False)
            x, y = make_x_y(data)
            a1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
            a1.plot(x, y)
            canvas.draw()
        except Empty:
            return

    root.after_idle(loop)  # start


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    q = Queue()
    q_2 = Queue()

    threading.Thread(target=poll_db, args=[1, q.put], daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=poll_db_2, args=[2, q_2.put], daemon=True).start()

    start_polling_loop(root, q, delay=40)
    start_polling_loop_2(root, q_2, delay=40)

    f = Figure(figsize=(8, 4), dpi=100)

    a = f.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    a1 = f.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте параметр `sharey`.

[Немного переделанный пример из документации по `matplotlib`:](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)

```
t = np.arange(0.01, 5.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)
#s3 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)

ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(t, s1)
plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=6)

# share y only
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, sharey=ax1)
# NOTE:  ------>       ^^^^^^^^^^
plt.plot(t, s2)
# make these tick labels invisible
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите, а как нарисовать 3 графика на одном рисунке с общим Х
без matplotlib?
Спасибо

Comment: @apis12, лучше задать отдельный вопрос и привести в нем небольшой пример входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе